# How do I adjust the position of plot labels in R using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given then the following dataframe and plot:

```
year = c(2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012)
pc = c(-.17, .0115, -.049, -.0116, -0.059, -.155)
df_test = data.frame(year, pc)

df_test %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=pc, label=pc)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text()
```

[image: year_pc_plot]

You can see that the labels interfere with the plot. I've tried to manually adjust the labels using `geom_text(hjust=0, vjust=-1, size=3)` but this takes a while to get it right.

Is there a way to have the plot labels automatically position themselves above/below or left/right (or alternating above/below left/right)?

Comment: For automated optimal positioning of labels, have a look at the [ggrepel](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html) package.

Comment: Using `geom_label` instead of `geom_text` is perhaps the easiest way to give a nice cosmetic result here.

Comment: I used `geom_text_repel(direction='both')` and there seems to be a marginal difference https://i.imgur.com/S0PoWk2.png I've tried the arguments listed in the documentation that you provided but it doesn't seem to be adjusting the position with respect to the plot line.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly concise and appealing way of drawing this kind of plot:

```r
df_test %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=pc, label=pc)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_label(fill = "gray92", label.size = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: With this particular dataset, the solution you provided works well. But I'm having trouble with my actual dataset: https://i.imgur.com/tRRnoke.png